# Conditionally print css style in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress theme and want to give the option to choose between a boxed layout and a full width layout.

For this purpose I created a variable in my header.php:

```
<head>
    <?php
        $isBoxedLayout = true;
    ?>
...
</head>
```

Down in the body I am asking if the variable is set:

```
<?php if($isBoxedLayout) { echo '<div id="boxed">'; } ?>
...
<?php if($isBoxedLayout) { echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

This works fine so far. But now I also want to change some css styles if this variable is set. My problem is that I am not so good in PHP yet so my solution would be something like this:

```
<head>
    <?php
        $isBoxedLayout = true;
    ?>
    ...
    if ($isBoxedLayout) {
        echo '<style type="text/css">';
        echo '#container {width:999px;}';
        echo '</style>';
    }
</head>
```

But I think this is not good programming because my header.php file would soon be full of code and confusing if I would add some other options. So logically I should create a variable or an array maybe in the functions.php file and outsource my code like this:

```
$isBoxedLayout = true;

if ($isBoxedLayout) {
    function boxed_css_styles() {
        echo '<style type="text/css">';
        echo '#container {width:999px;}';
        echo '</style>';
    }
}
```

Is my thinking right? And if so how would I access the functions I create in my index.php or header.php or whatever. Or would it work to print the styles in the functions.php?

best regards

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I thnik you post looks good, but it should rather be posted in the [Stack dedicated to Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). You might also search for related answers there.

Comment: i would consider having seperate classes for both situations and assign them to the relative elements by a simple if clause. this way you'll have to write very little php.

Comment: I would suggest that you just make two templates, one with the "boxed layout" and one without. Then the user may choose the template they wish in the admin area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't over-complicate this by trying to add styles via PHP. Add the ID via PHP...but not the styles themselves.

Since you only apply the `boxed` ID when the boxed layout is in effect, you can simply define some `#boxed` CSS styles. These styles will ONLY be applied if the ID exists in your markup...which means they won't come into effect when the ID isn't applied by your PHP.

In other words, put this in your CSS stylesheet, and forget about it:

```
#boxed {
    width: 999px;
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to change the styles of other Elements if the boxed element is added? For example if I have a #footer with 980px width and with #boxed added the #footer should have 100% width.

Comment: Then add it to the CSS...For example, if you want to change the paragraphs `<p>` when `boxed` is active, you could define it in your CSS as: `#boxed p { font-size: 16px }`, for example. Or...`#boxed #footer { /* some styles */ }` assuming the footer is nested.

Comment: If the footer isn't nested, you can add a class to all of your elements when `boxed` is active that does something similar. There are many solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A flexible option would be to use the `body_class()` function to add an additional class to your body tag. This would allow you to scope your styles accordingly:

.boxed section {
        /* Styles here */
   }
   .full-width section {
        /* Styles here */
   }

By adding the class on the body you can effectively target everything. This way you're keeping your styles separate from your markup.

Another option would be to keep your universal styles in one stylesheet and then load an additional stylesheet for your full-width/boxed specific styles. This can be handy for organisational purposes, by does add an extra http request, so you'd need to consider bear that in mind.